# how to install cakephp on cpanel?

Tags: cakephp

I tried to install cakephp om cpanel, but it does not work because of directory sturucture as i think

if you provide me with guide line

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how did you install it on cpanel, all you need to do is download it and unpack the contents then set the document root of your website to the webroot folder in the unpacked files? I assume your using Apache as the webserver so it should be easy enough although I'm not familiar with cpanel.